# Push notification triggered by approval process

Tags: approval-process, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush-ios

I need a way to trigger push notification when a approval is assigned to a user. I have set up everything neaded for push notification and can send push notifications from execute anonymous. I cant find a way to integrate this code so that it is executed depending on approval process steps because I cant create a trigger on approval process related objects ike ApprovalProcessInstanve, ProcessWorkStep ...
Salesforce1 which uses MobileSDK under the hood is doing this so I assume there is some way to achieve this.